# How to override a function that has static function

Tags: javascript

I have a function in the global scope that has you can call that function like that

```
var b =  blob();
```

but also it using as a name space with static function and has

```
var b = blob.parse();
```

I want to override blob() function without destroying the function on blob.parse

Comment: Attach `.parse()` function to your new function (prior overriding) and then override `blob` with that new function.

Comment: There's a puzzling typo (I think) in the first code line. You mean both times bl**o**b, not bl**a**b once, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've overwritten the old function, you need to copy all its properties to the new function:

```
blob = (function (original) {
    // new function body
    function blob() {
        blob.apply(this, arguments);   // "super" call to old function?
        // do whatever you want
    }
    // assuming it's a constructor:
    blob.prototype = original.prototype; // reset prototype
    blob.prototype.constructor = blob; // fix constructor property
    // regardless:
    for (var p in original)
        blob[p] = original[p];
    return blob;
})(blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function blob() {
  return {
    "test": "Yes"
  };
}

blob.prototype.parse = function() {
  return "parse function";
}
var b = blob(),
c = blob.prototype.parse();
console.log(b, c);


var copyprototype = Object.create(blob.prototype);

var blob = function() {
  return {
    "test" : "overridden"
  }
}
blob.prototype = Object.create(copyprototype);

var d = blob(),
e = blob.prototype.parse();
console.log(d, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that tries to build a fresh object. The concept is related to cloning, therefore be careful if your original `blob` object is anyhow deep.

Given is:

```
var b = function () { console.log("b"); }
b.parse = function() { console.log("parse"); }
```

Alterations are:

```
var newB = function() { console.log("the new b"); }
for (key in b) {
    newB[key] = b[key];
}
```

Result:

```
newB();
>>>> the new b
newB.parse();
>>>> parse
```